# Inconsistent indentation error when trying to run my script

Tags: python

I keep getting:

```
File "app.py", line 59
df = pd.DataFrame(list(db.mycol.find({}))), inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

I don't know what's causing the problem. I already tried to detab it. I'm using sublime text. Any advice?

```
def gen_wind_speed(interval):
    now = dt.datetime.now()
    sec = now.second
    minute = now.minute
    hour = now.hour

    total_time = (hour * 3600) + (minute * 60) + (sec)
    client = MongoClient(port=27017)

    db = client.one
    mycol = client['coll']

    df = pd.DataFrame(list(db.mycol.find({})))
```

Comment: "I already tried to detab it" - the edit view clearly shows you still have tabs.

Comment: You have tabs in front of your last two lines

Comment: Go into your editor's menu and hit "convert tabs to spaces".

Comment: I already did it. When i try to run the script from IDLE it runs, but when i run it from my shell it won't run

Comment: I did what @ThierryLathuille suggested and it's working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests, and I that think you understand, *somewhere* there is an `inconsistent use of tabs and spaces`. The line that you are getting an error on doesn't always mean that the error is happening on that line. The tab/space error could be anywhere above it.

If you've already redone all the spacing in this function to 4 spaces, as is the holy commandment, I would look above this function definition. Worst case, you have to use the search tool to find the tabs.

Comment: I have been suggested to convert indentation to space, it worked!